# bash assign variable with parameters with space in value

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I need to pass `--external-downloader ffmpeg --external-downloader-args -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov` through my `ytdlExtraOptions` variable to one my bash functions (defined in my `.bash_functions`) as 4 arguments :

```
$ set -- --external-downloader ffmpeg --external-downloader-args -movflags\ frag_keyframe+empty_moov
$ echo $4
-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov
$ ytdlExtraOptions="--external-downloader ffmpeg --external-downloader-args -movflags\\ frag_keyframe+empty_moov"
$ set -- $ytdlExtraOptions
$ echo $4
-movflags\
```

with a bash array :

```
$ ytdlExtraOptions=(--external-downloader ffmpeg --external-downloader-args -movflags\ frag_keyframe+empty_moov)
$ echo ${ytdlExtraOptions[3]}
-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov
$ set -- ${ytdlExtraOptions[@]}
$ echo $4
-movflags
```

How can I assign my `ytdlExtraOptions` variable correctly ?

Comment: You literally can't. Use a bash array.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm going to rewrite my question with a bash array.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. It'd be cool to clarify please.

Comment: @LéaGris I rewrote my question to clarify things. If it's more understandable, please undo your downvote :)

Comment: You already assign it, but please add double quotes around your array variable reference: `set -- "${ytdlExtraOptions[@]}"` and it will properly set your arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bash array.

```
set -- --external-downloader ffmpeg --external-downloader-args "-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov"
toto=("$@")
set -- "${toto[@]}"
echo $4
```

Alternatively you can use evil `eval` and `printf "%q "` to properly quote and re-evaulate your args:

```
set -- --external-downloader ffmpeg --external-downloader-args "-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov"
toto=$(printf "%q " "$@")
eval set -- "$toto"
```